# PrimeFaces DataTable: how to use a var="item" as a variable in getting rowStyle for example?

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I mean this. I have a JSF page with a PrimeFaces Datatable, and I want to get a rowstyleClass name from bean. But bean method should check a record from table to return a String value of styleClass.

can I do something like this

```
@ManagedBean(name="styleController")
@SessionScoped
public class StyleController {

    public StyleController() {
    }

    public String getContractStyle(ContrMain contrMain){ //ContrMain - entity class
        if(contrMain.getCloseDate()!=null && contrMain.getClosedBy()!=null){
            return "closed";
        }else{
            return "acting";
        }
    }
}
```

and in JSF page something like this

```
<p:dataTable value="#{contrMainController.items}" 
             var="item" 
             ...
             rowStyleClass="ui-datatable-#{styleController.contractStyle(item)}">
```

I know that it doesn't work. And is there some way to use an "item" variable?

Answer (score 2):

I have found decision.

the answer is simple.

```
rowStyleClass="ui-datatable-#{styleController.getContractStyle(item)}"
```

instead of

```
rowStyleClass="ui-datatable-#{styleController.contractStyle(item)}"
```

works fine